# Node - Test if function call with 2 arguments using mocha/chai

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mocha.js, chai

How can i test if function call with 2 arguments using mocha/chai?

```
describe('EncryptCode Test', () => {

   it('EncryptCode function return a string', () => {
    expect(EncryptCode.Encrypt('fArgs','sArgs')).to.be.an('string');
   });

   it('EncryptCode function call with 2 arguments', () => {
     ???????????
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some analysis/manipulation on the stringified function declaration.

```js
let args = EncryptCode.Encrypt.toString().match(/\((.*)\)/)[1].split(',');
expect(args).length(2);
```

Comment: Best to add supporting text to your code snippets so they don't get flagged for deletion